# SwiftUI: Update views when conditions / ObservableObject changed while view is opened

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I guess it is mostlikely a stupid question, but currently I am struggling.
To avoid tons of code, I simplified the code (see below) but it should show the problem.

I’ve got multiple views that are not in a parental relationship.
On one view (ViewA) I set a target date. On another view (ViewB) I show text, depending on the fact whether the target date is in future or not.
For both views I am using a ObservableObject.
I would like to have that ViewB changes the text when it is open and the target date is reached at that time. Since I am using the tag @Published, I was expecting it works directly.
But unfortunately, nothing happens.

This is my initial approach.

I tested some more solutions, e.g.

1. polling by a timer in the views with a function to get the current date
2. I also thought about first calculating the remaining time and a timer in another thread within the ObservedObject that fires an event when the timer reaches 0 and onReceive modifiers in the views.

But I guess my approach(es) is (are) very bad I there will be a way better solution.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks, 
Sebastian

**SearchData:**

```
class SearchData: ObservableObject {

   @Published var targetDate: Date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "targetDate") as? Date ?? Date() {
       didSet {
           UserDefaults.standard.set(self.targetDate, forKey: "targetDate")
       }
   }
}
```

**View A:**

```
struct ViewA: View {
   @ObservedObject var searchData = SearchData()

   func setDate() {
       searchData.targetDate = Date() + 120
   }

   var body: some View {

       Button(action: {
           self.setDate()
       }) {
           Text("Set Date")
       }
   }
}
```

**View B:**

```
struct ViewB: View {
   @ObservedObject var searchData = SearchData()

   var body: some View {
       VStack() {
           if searchData.targetDate > Date() {
               Text("Text A")
           } else {
               Text("Text B")
           }
           Spacer()
           Text("\(searchData.targetDate)")
       }
       .padding()
   }
}
```

Comment: check this logic(searchData.targetDate > Date()) and  change Date() in to something... I feel like this is where the problem. actually I didn't run this in my Mac, if you getting always Text("Text A") ... then problem is just right here.

Comment: Thank you! I really re-thought the logic of my condition and actually, it didn't really make sense what I did. Now I have got a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewA` and `ViewB` use different instances of `SearchData`. To make published work directly, as you wrote, both views have to use **one** instance of observable object.

```
struct ViewA: View {
   @ObservedObject var searchData: SearchData
   /// ... other code

struct ViewB: View {
   @ObservedObject var searchData: SearchData
   /// ... other code
```

and somewhere you crate them

```
let searchData = SearchData()
...

ViewA(searchData: searchData)

...

ViewB(searchData: searchData)
```

If `ViewA` and `ViewB` live in different view hierarchies then probably would be more appropriate to use `@EnvironmentObject`

```
struct ViewA: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var searchData: SearchData
   /// ... other code

struct ViewB: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var searchData: SearchData
   /// ... other code
```